# Call control function

Tags: vb.net

I have a control with 2 function: func1 and func2
I have a form with a list of controls.
I want to have a single function (I'll call it MainFunc) on my form which iterate all controls in my list and calls func1 or func2 according to a parameter.
I suppose it'll look something like that:

public sub MainFunc(CalledFunc as ???)

```
for each IteratedControl as CustomControl in MyControlList
    IteratedControl.invoke(CalledFunc)
end for
```

end sub

I don't want my parameter to be an enum and according to its value calling the correct function because there are a lot of functions and not just 2 as in the above examples.

please help

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each control In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf control Is CustomControl Then
  CType(control, CustomControl ).func1()                
  CType(control, CustomControl ).func2()                
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Let me explain myself better. Not all the functions are run. only one, according to the passed parameter in MainFunc. But I don't want to use an enum. The passed parameter should be some kind of delegate (I suppose). Thanks

Comment: Why not just using an Event?